# How do we save the question about an offensive remark by a teacher?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

The question: [How do I defend my self against the allegation that I made an inappropriate, culturally offensive statement in class?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/77253/how-do-i-defend-my-self-against-the-allegation-that-i-made-an-inappropriate-cul)

I think this is a question that we should be able to tackle.  Is there some way we can save this question?  Being a teacher is a job and this is about navigating the workplace if you work at a school. Can we save it?

Note there are no answers so if we need to do a significant edit for the question to be saved - at least we have that option.

Comment: I inadvertently migrated it to academia, too, I didn't realize they don't take questions regarding non-college level questions..

Comment: @enderland - I didnt either I thought It would be a good question for them.

Comment: The question has too much missing information for it to be meaningfully answerable.

Comment: For the benefit of low-rep users, what is the content of the question?

Comment: Isn't this the plot of [*The Human Stain*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Human_Stain) by Philip Roth?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it can be edited to be a good question without fundamentally changing it. It's too disjointed and comes across as a one-sided rant justifying some underlying hidden reason for a reprimand.

A better question is 'How can I deal with a reprimand I feel is unjustified where I am unable to defend myself'

Answer (score 3):

I think that the wordiness and emotion coming through made it come across as more of a rant.  Here's what I propose as an edit.  Please feel free to alter or suggest changes.

SUGGESTED EDIT:

The sub coordinator for the county said the school's report stated that a student had reported that I had reprimanded a few male students in a class and had said something regarding the school's culture being one of behaving with equal respect toward both men and women teachers.

This arose from an incident where I politely, quietly admonished three disrespectful students who continued to talk after I had asked them to please listen as I was giving instructions regarding what the class had been assigned to do by their teacher. I  did not "write them up" because I did not want their records to be tarnished because of a relatively minor infraction.

I have not been given the opportunity to respond to the allegations levied against me. There has been no dialogue or opportunity to discuss the problems and make right any misunderstandings that arose out of my comment that day.

What would be a good strategy to address this with my superiors to correct this misunderstanding?

Comment: but it doesn't make any sense. "I am being written up for telling students that we should all be polite! What should I do?" The OP needs to edit it to explain why it would be bad to have said the gender thing, along with whether or not OP actually said the gender thing. My biggest problem with that question is I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: @KateGregory It's the PC thought police, and the OP has no idea what he did wrong.  The answer is nothing, of course, but he wants to know how to smooth things over.  I've seen people crucified like this before

Comment: There may be a disconnect between the actual words used by the teacher  vs. the sentiment expressed in the question.  Without knowing the words, we can't hypothesize whether the accusation is meaningful.  Phrasing that teacher thought was "politely,quietly" admonishing could have been offensive.  How to handle a false accusation is different from how to handle poor choice of words.

Comment: @cdkMoose It sounds like a false accusation.

Comment: Certainly sounds like OP thinks it is, but is (s)he objective enough?  I grew up in a very ethnically isolated area.  When I first moved to a more urban setting, I am certain that I made unknowingly rude/insensitive comments.  I have since spent my entire working life in culturally and ethnically diverse environments and am much more cognizant of those issues.  Not sure where OP is on that spectrum

Comment: @cdkMoose The OP made a point of having been exposed to a broad spectrum of people.  It sounds like cases that I have been involved in. ,  I was defending people who were accused, in some cases against people offended on my behalf.  Another thing that is a dead giveaway is the fact that the OP was given no opportunity to speak on their own behalf.

Comment: Didn't see anything to that effect in the suggested edit and I didn't reread the original, sorry.  I certainly understand your perspective but I've also seen "educated" people insist their insensitive remark wasn't insensitive.

Comment: @cdkMoose Well, there is that.  I've had an "educated" person try to correct me about some of the disabilities I live with.